# Asp.net MVC3 web application server response time issue

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

my site is taking almost over 5 seconds to load, but all other sites hosted on the same server are working fine and opening fast. They all are pointed to the same DNS.

I am using the same connection helper class to open the connection to the MS Sql express 2008 express R2 (SP1) for all the sites:

```
public class ConnectionHelper : IConnectionHelper
{
    public ObjectContext Connection
    {
        get
        {
            if (_connection == null && HttpContext.Current.Items["DbActiveContext"] != null)
            {
                _connection = (cpusortEntities)HttpContext.Current.Items["DbActiveContext"];
            }
            else
            {
                _connection = new cpusortEntities(ConnectionString);
                //HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("DbActiveContext", _connection);
                HttpContext.Current.Items["DbActiveContext"] = _connection;
            }
            return _connection;
        }
    }
    private ObjectContext _connection;

    public string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cpusortEntities"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried almost everything in IIS 7.5, increased worker processes to 2 to make it a web garden but no luck.

Any help what should I do? Please help me out, Thanks

Comment: Have you tried any profiling so far? Try some of these [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/), [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/). You would need to identify bottlenecks before optimizing.

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan: Actually www.cpusort.com/Sort/All page loads normally, only home www.cpusort.com and www.cpusort.com/cpus/..... takes time to load. Response graph show there is a response time delay average of 5 seconds. I have over 1 million URLs, and few days ago I made sitemaps of them and sent them to Google webmasters tools and set the crawl rate to maximum. yesterday over 45000 pages crawled by Google bot. Should be crawl rate be a problem?

Comment: I highly recommend New Relic. They have a free version that will tell you where your site is slow.

Comment: @ArbazAbid - could you check if this was a transient issue, i.e are your pages still slow? As John mentions, you could use something like NewRelic that logs CPU and Memory usage along with requests. It could well be that sudden upsurge of traffic overloaded your server.

Comment: @JohnTseng: I just found out by look into UI of worker process in real time in IIS, that my home page, www.cpusort.com/cpus/... and www.cpusort.com/cpu/... are using too much private memory bytes and processor. I think It many be because I am using too much If Else conditions on these pages in View (over 230 If condtions on .../cpus/.. page to compare data in View and Images are showing on these pages are also re-sizing on the fly and I am also setting up its cache and expiration. BUT I have deleted both Views in order to monitor the change. I don't know why Home View is eating too much memory

Comment: @ArbazAbid Conditional flow control like if/else do not use much memory at all. It's the data that you are comparing that uses memory. Maybe those pages make a lot of queries to the database. Image resizing is a very resource intensive process. You should definitely cache that.

Comment: @JohnTseng: I am caching the images, and its working fine. I thought may be re-sizing on the fly can use more memory. I used a lot of If/Else on View to generate the conditional HTML. Few days ago my server was notifying for new updates, After that this problem started I guess so.